# Getting java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Unsupported feature: checkValidIndex Exception

Tags: java, spring-jdbc

I am getting exception when running below code. It is written in Java 8 and using ojdbc8 jar for data base connection. And db is Oracle 12.2.0.1.0.

```
String insertQuery = generateSql(Utils.getStringArray(ApplicationConstants.INSERT_REQUEST_RESPONSE));

srpJdbcTemplate.update(insertQuery,new Object[] { null, broadSoftResponse.getTransType(), broadSoftResponse.getRequestXml(),
broadSoftResponse.getResponseXml(), null, null, null, null, null,
ApplicationConstants.SOURCE_SYSTEM, ApplicationConstants.SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID,
broadSoftResponse.getTrackingId(), null });
```

And the query is used -  `INSERT INTO INTERFACE_TRANS(INT_TRANS_ID,ORD_NP_DETAIL_ID,TRANS_TYPE,REQUEST,RESPONSE,STATUS,ERROR_CODE,ERROR_MESSAGE,START_TIME,END_TIME,SOURCE_SYSTEM,SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID,TRACKING_ID,REF1) VALUES(SRP.INT_TRANS_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)`

The Exception -

```
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate  - Executing prepared SQL statement [INSERT INTO SRP.INTERFACE_TRANS(INT_TRANS_ID,ORD_NP_DETAIL_ID,TRANS_TYPE,REQUEST,RESPONSE,STATUS,ERROR_CODE,ERROR_MESSAGE,START_TIME,END_TIME,SOURCE_SYSTEM,SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID,TRACKING_ID,REF1) VALUES(SRP.INT_TRANS_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)]
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils  - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils  - Could not check database or driver name
java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Unsupported feature: checkValidIndex
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleParameterMetaData.checkValidIndex(OracleParameterMetaData.java:196)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleParameterMetaData.getParameterType(OracleParameterMetaData.java:307)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setNull(StatementCreatorUtils.java:241)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:214)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:145)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgPreparedStatementSetter.doSetValue(ArgPreparedStatementSetter.java:65)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgPreparedStatementSetter.setValues(ArgPreparedStatementSetter.java:46)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:816)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:1)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:587)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:812)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:868)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:876)
```

Could you please share your thoughts to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use [`update(String sql, Object... args)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) when you have null values, use [`update(String sql, Object[] args, int[] argTypes)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#update-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-int:A-) instead, so you can tell the `JdbcTemplate` what the value types are.

That way it doesn't need to call the `getParameterType` JDBC method for null values.

*Example*

```
srpJdbcTemplate.update(insertQuery, new Object[] {
    null, broadSoftResponse.getTransType(), broadSoftResponse.getRequestXml(),
    broadSoftResponse.getResponseXml(), null, null, null, null, null,
    ApplicationConstants.SOURCE_SYSTEM, ApplicationConstants.SOURCE_SYSTEM_ID,
    broadSoftResponse.getTrackingId(), null
}, new int[] {
    Types.INTEGER, Types.INTEGER, Types.VARCHAR,
    Types.VARCHAR, Types.DATE, Types.DATE, Types.INTEGER, Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR,
    Types.VARCHAR, Types.INTEGER,
    Types.INTEGER, Types.VARCHAR
});
```

Of course, not having a clue what your column types actually are, that is just an example.